# apply parameter into function within parameter array

Tags: javascript, callback

http://jsbin.com/ukizof/1/
how do you call a function which is part of a array and set a paramater to it , as in the example below i want the script to return a function in order to call a function parameter which as below in the example is set below.

```
   var bQuery = {
        one: function(elem, options) {
            options = this.extend({
                method: 'html',
                event: 'test2',
              func:null
            }, options || {});
            var element = elem;

            if (options.method == 'html') {
                element.innerHTML = options.event;
            } else if (options.method == 'append') {
                element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + options.event;
            } else if (options.method == 'prepend') {
                element.innerHTML = options.event + element.innerHTML;

            }
          return // return method to apply string to func: parameter function as below is "e"


        },
        extend: function(a, b) {
            for (var prop in b) {
                a[prop] = b[prop];
            }
            return a;
        }
    };
    $ = bQuery;
    $.one(document.getElementById("log"), {
        method: 'append',
        event: 'rjfjfjjffj',
        func: function(e){
          alert(e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you actually want to return a function, or do you just want to apply the `func` with parameters? What do you mean by "*force string to func*"?

Comment: i want to apply a value to the function where func: `function(e){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want

```
var options, element;
…
return function() {
    if (typeof options.func == 'function')
        return options.func(element.innerHTML);
};
```